# Convert Log macro to objective C string

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

We have a C++ library with the below DebugLog macro which writes to a file

```
    std::string var("some string");
    DebugLog( << "Output" << var );
```

We want to use this in our Objective C code so that both the ObjC and C++ library are writing to the same log file.

In our existing ObjC we use a log macro which when used with format parameters produces no warning from compiler

```
    LOG("Error description %s", [[error  localizedDescription] UTF8String]);
```

However all usages without format parameters produce warnings eg

```
    LOG("initialising")
```

The LOG macro is defined as shown below and is generating a warning 'Format string is not a string literal'. Anyone know how to improve the code to remove this warning.

```
 #define LOG(fmt, ...) do { \
      NSString *tmp =[NSString stringWithFormat:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:fmt], ##__VA_ARGS__];   \
      DebugLog( << [ tmp UTF8String] ); \
 }   while(0) \
```

Comment: What C++ library are you using? You may be able to just figure out the file and keep `NSLog`

Comment: sorry we can't modify the library

Comment: If you use your macros passing an NSString into it like this: `LOG(@"format", params)` then you probably don't need `stringWithUTF8String` in the code.

Comment: We have thousands of these LOG statements so wanted to resolve it this way rather than attempting to change like that if possible

Comment: Haven't done C++ is donkeys years, but almost all functions that take a format string will emit a warning if your try to pass a variable for that format. The danger is that the variable string may contain characters that get interpreted ("progress is 50% complete") may cause odd behavior or crashes. The "solution" is to pass the variable as a variable, so something like `"%s",tmp.UTF8String`, in however you'd write that in the ugly-operator-overload-abused world of C++ these days.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include a sample use of your `LOG` macro and the output it currently produces?

Comment: @CRD  Done that. Actually noticed that when using format parameters in the LOG macro there are no warnings. It was just that 90% of the log statements don't use format parameters so we assumed that all were causing warnings.

Comment: @tech74 - Please check your first definition of `LOG` in your question - it doesn't make sense as is (the `(@"%s" fmt)` - it is *valid* syntax, but probably not what you wrote).

Comment: Yes, that was what we were using originally but we have changed it to the macro at the bottom. We've removed it now from the original post  as its causing confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your examples it appears you are using `LOG` with a C-string as the format string, on that basis your original `NSLog` version could be:

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) NSLog(@fmt,  ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

*provided* `fmt` is always a literal string. Macros operate *before* lexical analysis (or at least effectively do so, dependent on implementation) – hence the term "pre-processor" for the part of the compiler which handles macros, conditional compilation, etc. Given this your macro example:

```
LOG("Error description %s", [[error  localizedDescription] UTF8String]);
```

expands to:

```
NSLog(@"Error description %s", [[error  localizedDescription] UTF8String]);
```

and the compiler sees the format string as an Objective-C string.

In a similar way you can rewrite your macro to use your C++ function as:

```
#define LOG(fmt, ...) DebugLog( [NSString stringWithFormat:@fmt,  ##__VA_ARGS__].UTF8String );
```

HTH